# Slick slider - Add class before li.slick-active dot

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have Slick Slider (*#my-slider*) and I want to add class (*.past*) to the all *.slick-dots li* elements **before** *li.slick-active* one.

how it currently looks
[image]

how I want it to look
[image]

**I tried the following:**

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
           var $items = slick.$dots.find('li.slick-active').prevAll();
           $items.addClass('past');
        });

        $('#my-slider').slick({
          dots: true,
          arrows: true,
          infinite: false,
          speed: 500,
          fade: true,
          autoplay: false,
          cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**and this one**

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         $('#my-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
           $('#my-slider .slick-dots li.slick-active').prevAll().addClass('past');
        });

        $('#my-slider').slick({
          dots: true,
          arrows: true,
          infinite: false,
          speed: 500,
          fade: true,
          autoplay: false,
          cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But no luck.

Slider works, but it doesn't give *past* class at all.

Comment: If you are using the `initialSlide` setting, the first slide will be active and you'll have no previous slides. You may wish to call your function on `beforeChange` instead of `init`, to add the class to the `currentSlide` value before it moves to the next slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `beforeChange` slick event to add/remove `.past` classes on all dots using the `nextSlide` value.

> Note: You do not need to use `jQuery(document).ready(function () { });` inside `(function ($) { })(jQuery);`. The first function is
> shorthand for doc ready, so you are calling doc ready twice. Remove
> `jQuery(document).ready(function () { });` as it is not needed.

See live demo below for your problem with comments in code...

```js
// our slick mySlider
let mySlider = $('#my-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  autoplay: true,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  pauseOnFocus: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000
});

// our mySlider dots
let dots = $('.slick-dots > LI', mySlider);

// before mySlider change slick event
mySlider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  // remove dot past classes on dots after next slide dot
  $(dots[nextSlide]).nextAll().removeClass('past');
  
  // add dot past classes on dots before next slide dot
  $(dots[nextSlide]).prevAll().addClass('past');
    
});
```

```css
/* my-slider dots active and past css */

#my-slider .slick-dots LI.slick-active BUTTON::before,
#my-slider .slick-dots LI.slick-active BUTTON:focus {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#my-slider .slick-dots LI.past BUTTON::before,
#my-slider .slick-dots LI.past BUTTON:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

#my-slider .slick-dots LI:not(.past) BUTTON:focus {
  opacity: .25;
}

/* my-slider demo css not needed */

BODY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#my-slider FIGURE {
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-slider">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
</div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Here is fiddle version too: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/mbrs3t9v/17/

Comment: Thank you . Works like a charm :) Combination of the beforeChange and nextSlide did the job. Thank you for "doc ready" clarification as well.

Comment: No worries the css focus can play havoc with the active pause states but this covers that too